# Permission denied Error while copying?

Tags: permissions

I am trying to copy a file from my Download directory to my Desktop directory; but I am getting the Permission Denied Error. Directory and file permissions doesn't restrict me from copying (Directory perm: 755 , file perm:- 664).

```
sockets@ankit:~$ ls -ld D
Desktop/   Documents/ Downloads/ 
sockets@ankit:~$ ls -ld Downloads/ Desktop/ 
drwxr-xr-x 9 sockets sockets 4096 Jan  4 12:52 Desktop/
drwxr-xr-x 3 sockets sockets 4096 Jan 10 16:24 Downloads/
sockets@ankit:~$ ls -l Downloads/Ankit.pdf 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sockets sockets 96170 Jan 10 16:24 Downloads/Ankit.pdf
sockets@ankit:~$ cp Downloads/Ankit.pdf Desktop/Ankit.pdf
cp: cannot create regular file `Desktop/Ankit.pdf': Permission denied
```

Any ideas why I would be getting the permission error. I know I can use sudo to copy the file.

----------EDIT -1

```
sockets@ankit:/var/log$ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       2501856 228878  2272978   10% /
udev             755379    510   754869    1% /dev
tmpfs            757578    431   757147    1% /run
none             757578      3   757575    1% /run/lock
none             757578      8   757570    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6      27639808  37521 27602287    1% /home/mount
```

----------EDIT 2

```
sockets@ankit:~$ df -h | grep /dev/sd
/dev/sda1        38G  8.5G   28G  24% /
/dev/sda6       416G   87G  308G  22% /home/mount
/dev/sdc1        16G  2.1G   14G  14% /media/New Volume
sockets@ankit:~$ mount | grep /dev/sd
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda6 on /home/mount type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/New Volume type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)
```

Comment: please run the command "df -i" and paste the output as an edit to your question.

Comment: i have pasted the output of df -i

Comment: OK, not it then.  If you run out of inodes it can cause a 'permission denied' error.  This isn't the problem apparently.

Comment: If you were root, you would be able to copy those files. But Since you are a normal user, you can only read contents of Desktop and execute files there. That's all. You don't have a write permission.

Does `sudo cp Downloads/Ankit.pdf Desktop/Ankit.pdf` work?

Comment: @Melon, directory permissions shows that I am file/Directory owner and have permission 755 and 644 means that I can do rwx on directory and rw on file.

Comment: Correct, you have the necessary permissions. I just replicated your situation as near as I am able and could not find a problem with syntax or logic.  'Scuse me asking the obvious, but the partition containing ~/ is not full (or mounted read only)?  Show us also the output of "df -h | grep /dev/sd" and "mount | grep /dev/sd"

Comment: @fabricator, the partition isn't full. But I have mounted /dev/sda6 on "(/dev/sda1/) mount- point:- /home/mount". Could that cause the issue.

Comment: I saw that on the df command output.  No it would not cause the problem.  See if you can create a normal empty file on the the desktop with the command "touch ~/Desktop/ttt.txt". Any error message?  If this fails as well try doing it with root permissions to test if it actually is a permissions problem: "sudo touch ~/Desktop/xxx.txt"

Comment: I am able to create an empty file with touch command; after using touch command to my surprise  I was allowed to use `cp Downloads/Ankit.pdf Desktop/Ankit.pdf`, I am not sure why this happened in the first place.

Comment: Ah yes, looked at wrong permissions. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another scenario that would cause the problem

```
chris@chris-desktop:~$ sudo cp Downloads/Ankit.pdf Desktop/Ankit.pdf
[sudo] password for chris: 
chris@chris-desktop:~$ ls -l Desktop/Ankit.pdf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19769 Jan 11 05:52 Desktop/Ankit.pdf
chris@chris-desktop:~$ cp Downloads/Ankit.pdf Desktop/Ankit.pdf
cp: cannot create regular file `Desktop/Ankit.pdf': Permission denied
```

In this case I already created a file in the destination directory with sudo so that it was owned by root.  The file can not be overwritten by a normal cp command as user and results in a 'Permiision denied' error.

Answer (score 2):

OK, strange that it worked OK after creating a file with touch.  I'm wondering if there's file system error of some sort in which case I'd strongly advise that you force an fsck check of the filesystem - Easily done.  Save all open files and in a terminal window:

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
sudo reboot
```

After the machine comes back up it will test the root partition and then boot into Ubuntu normally.  It may prompt you for permission to repair the file system or tell you what problems if any have been fixed.